# phpunit 8 and PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

Tags: php, phpunit

I wrote the following test:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
//other uses

class StatusCheckerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testEntryValidation() {
        //some code
        $this->assertFalse($validation_result);
   }

}
```

I tried to run it with `phpunit StatusCheckerTest.php`
But when I do it, I see error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in 
/var/www/html/nextcloud/apps/globalstatus/tests/OCA/GlobalStatus/Tests/StatusCheckerTest.php on line 12
```

I used PHPUnit 8.4.3 (also tried with 6.5.5). I installed it manually.

```
phpunit --version
PHPUnit 8.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Why does it look for `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`? It must be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run only a specific test class, you need to pass it with a `filter` option:

```
phpunit --filter StatusCheckerTest
```